# Borewell motor water outlet adjustment

Tags: motors, pumps, water-resources

Recently we put 500 feet borewell in our area, it's hot summer season now. Person who drilled the borewell told me that we can get 1.5 inch of water now. During winter season we can expect at least 2 inch of water. Now we are planning to install the motor at 410 feet and buy 5hp motor with 2 inch mouth.

My question is
Can I put 2 inch pipe inside borewell and control water outlet at the end of borewell with 1.5 inch? Whenever water level increase can I increase outlet with 2 inch? Can I control water outlet at the end?

Question rephrased:

Can we adjust water outlet of the submersible motor at the ground surface or edge of the pipe? Usually people adjust water outlet at the end of motor mouth section which is inside the borewell not at the ground. Is there any signigficance where the reducer kept?

Comment: Could you please make a drawing please, I'm not sure I understand your question completely :D

Comment: I'm not sure how to draw it. I will rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either. But the drop pipe should be sized for structural reasons to the depth of the well, and it usually matches the pump outlet. It won't hurt anything. Are you running this thing to an open sluice continually? Is that why you are asking about restricting the flow rate? At an estimated flow rate of 20gpm for 5hp pump @ 400ft of head, the pump will barely notice the difference between 1.5 and 2". 1.5" pipe friction loss will be about 4% of head at 20gpm. If the water level is high, initial flow rate will be higher, but the pipe size won't effectively regulate output.